# A common Graph use case algorithm implementation in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have data in pairs in following format in a file on hadoop:

`A|B 
B|C 
C|D 
E|F 
F|X 
Y|Z`

I need to find out the connected nodes i.e. i would need the output in 3 sets:

```
A|B,B|C,C|D
E|F,F|X
Y|Z
```

Logic being all the nodes that are connected with an element must be collected together.

Size of data : Around 1 Billion Pairs. 170 Million unique elements.

Any suggestions on how i could implement this using MR or Hive QL would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding Connected Components using Hadoop/MapReduce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677388/finding-connected-components-using-hadoop-mapreduce)

Comment: Thanks! This is a duplicate. marking this as answered.